# Can I use the variable name specified in the do syntax immediately? In batch file

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I want to find file list PATH1
and overwrite it if there is a file with the same name on PATH2.

```
@echo off

SET PATH1="FIND_PATH"
SET PATH2="OVERWRITE_PATH"

for /f "delims=" %%A in ('dir /b %PATH1%') do (
    dir /s /b /r %PATH2% | find /i "%%A" > list.txt
    SET /p PATH3<=list.txt
    move %PATH1%%%A %PATH3%
)
```

At line 7,
If possible, it would be nice to store it in a variable without going through list.txt in the middle.

I perform "ECHO %PATH3%" outside the for syntax, the last saved item is output.
but I perform "ECHO %PATH3%" inside the do syntax, Outputs an error.

how can I do.

thx.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Variables are not behaving as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30282784/variables-are-not-behaving-as-expected) Specifically, add `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` under the `@echo off` and use `!PATH3!` instead of `%PATH3%`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my analysis of your code:

```
for /f "delims=" %%A in ('dir /b %PATH1%') do (
  rem %%A contains filename + extension of each file AND DIRECTORY in path1
    dir /s /b /r %PATH2% | find /i "%%A" > list.txt
  rem LIST.txt contains full pathnames of all filenames AND DIRECTORIES
  rem where "%%A" forms part of the full pathname
    SET /p PATH3<=list.txt
  rem PATH3 contains the first line of list.txt
    move %PATH1%%%A %PATH3%
  rem move `path1%%A` (a file or directoryname - but without the `\` separator)
  rem to the first (probably filename) found
)
```

Comment : first time in using batch for the last 40 years that I've ever seen the `/r` swich used in a `dir` statement...

So - we have to make some reasonable assumptions as to the intent of this code.

Tip: Use `set "var=value"` for setting string values - this avoids problems caused by trailing spaces. Don't assign `"` or a terminal backslash or Space. Build pathnames from the elements - counterintuitively, it is likely to make the process easier. If the syntax `set var="value"` is used, then the quotes become part of the value assigned.

```
@echo off

SET "PATH1=FIND_PATH"
SET "PATH2=OVERWRITE_PATH"

for /f "delims=" %%b in ('dir /b /a-d "%PATH1%"') do (
  for /f "delims=" %%u in ('dir /s /b /a-d /r "%PATH2%\%%b" 2^>nul') do (
    ECHO move "%PATH1%\%%A" "%%u"
  )
)
```

[1] Change to better `set` syntax
[2] Prefer to avoid ADFNPSTXZ (in either case) as metavariables (loop-control variables) as ADFNPSTXZ are metavariable-modifiers which can lead to difficult-to-find bugs (See `for/f` from the prompt for documentation)
[3] Include `/a-d` to exclude directory names from `dir` lists
[4] Include `%%b` in the filemask for the inner `for` to search for that exact name only in the destination directory-tree
[5] The `2^>nul` suppresses an error message should no files be found in the destination-tree matching the filename. The caret (`^`) is required to tell `cmd` that the `>` is part of the `dir` command, not the `for`
[6] Append the filename found (`%%b`) to the source directoryname with required separator
[7] `%%u` will contain the full pathnames of the matching files in the destination directory-tree
[8] The resultant command is merely `echo`ed for verification. After verification, remove the `echo` keyword to actually execute the `move`.

**Untested**

**Always verify against a test directory before applying to real data.**

The effect would be to find all of the filenames in the source directory and `move` it over all matching filenames in the destination directory tree.

**LOGICAL FLAW**
a "move" command would move a file `a.txt` over the first `a.txt` in the destination-tree. Then the source file no longer exists (as it's been moved) so if a second `a.txt` is located in the destination-tree, then the `move` will fail.

Consider this further modification:

```
@echo off

SET "PATH1=FIND_PATH"
SET "PATH2=OVERWRITE_PATH"

for /f "delims=" %%b in ('dir /b /a-d "%PATH1%"') do (
  set "moved="
  for /f "delims=" %%u in ('dir /s /b /a-d /r "%PATH2%\%%b" 2^>nul') do (
    set "moved=y"
    ECHO COPY "%PATH1%\%%A" "%%u"
  )
  if defined moved (
   ECHO del "%PATH1%\%%A"
  ) else (
   ECHO "%PATH1%\%%A" - no matches in tree "%PATH2%" found
   ECHO MOVE "%PATH1%\%%A" "%PATH2%"
  )
)
```

This change sets `moved` to *nothing* for each source file found, then sets it to `y` if any matching filename is found n the destination tree.

If the file *has* been copied, then delete the source file, otherwise complain and move it to the destination-tree-root.